# Python SQLite3 function not printing any data

Tags: python, sqlite

I have created a function that is supposed to send all the items, with a stock level of less than 10, in my database to a text file. But i am not receiving any data when I press the reorder button.

```
def Database():
    global conn, cursor
    conn = sqlite3.connect("main_storage.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (admin_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, username TEXT, password TEXT)")
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (product_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, product_name TEXT, product_qty TEXT, product_price TEXT)")
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `basket` (product_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, product_name TEXT, product_qty TEXT, product_price TEXT)")
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `username` = 'admin' AND `password` = 'admin'")
    if cursor.fetchone() is None:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `admin` (username, password) VALUES('admin', 'admin')")
        conn.commit()

def reorder():
    global items
    Database()
    cursor.execute("SELECT `product_name` FROM `product` WHERE `product_qty` <= 10")
    items = cursor.fetchall()
    print(items)
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

I expect the output to be an array of items within my database e.g. [44, 'motherboard', 9, 80] where 44 is product_id, motherboard is product_name, 9 is product_stock and 80 is product_price. I am actually getting an array with nothing in like: []

Comment: you didn't insert anything in to the `product` table as the code shows so that is why nothing is returned

Comment: sorry, that is because I haven't posted my whole code, there are items within the database.

Comment: What gives `"SELECT * FROM product` ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM product` gives `[(59, 'test', '8', '10.0')]` as that is the only item i have in my database at the minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`product_qty` is defined as a *TEXT* column, so comparisons like `<=` will be performed between the *string* values of operands.  This may not give the results that you expect:

```
>>> '8' < '10'
False
```

Recreate your tables with *INTEGER* or *REAL* as the column type for numeric values to get the behaviour that you want.  For example:

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` """
               """(product_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"""
               """product_name TEXT, product_qty INTEGER, product_price REAL)""")
```

Comment: Thank you very much